# Implementing BST in javascript

Tags: javascript, tree, search

Is this an efficient and clean implementation?

```
function BST(items) {
    this.tree = {};
    if (items) items.forEach(this.add, this);
}

BST.prototype.add = function(item) {
    if (!this.tree.value) {
        this.tree.value = item;
        return item;
    }
    var currNode = this.tree;
    var inserted = false;
    while (!inserted) {
        if (item > currNode.value) {
            if (currNode.rightNode) currNode = currNode.rightNode;
            else {
                currNode.rightNode = {
                    value: item
                };
                inserted = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (currNode.leftNode) currNode = currNode.leftNode;
            else {
                currNode.leftNode = {
                    value: item
                };
                inserted = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return item;
};

BST.prototype.printTree = function() {
    console.log(this.tree);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Interface

Why return the value added? That's unusual and unexpected.

#### Bug

It's unusual to allow adding duplicate values.
It would be better to ignore.

#### Avoid flag variables when possible

The flag variable `inserted` is unnecessary.

```
while (true) {
    if (item > currNode.value) {
        if (currNode.rightNode) currNode = currNode.rightNode;
        else {
            currNode.rightNode = {
                value: item
            };
            return;
        }
    } else {
        if (currNode.leftNode) currNode = currNode.leftNode;
        else {
            currNode.leftNode = {
                value: item
            };
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I replaced the `insert = true` statements with `return`.
If you *really* want to `return item`, then you can either use that instead of `return`, or use `break`.